# changing the footer font size to 12 pt and footer margin to .8 in

Tags: margins, fontsize, size, footer

I need to change the footer font size to 12pt and the footer margin to 0.8 inches.

```
\documentclass[]{report} 

\usepackage[md]{titlesec} %required for section titles
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[verbose]{cite} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}%margins
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}%
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em} 
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}

\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}%
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\doublespacing %double space
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\large

\vspace*{2in}
Ic\\
\vspace{2in}
By\\
J
\vspace{1in}
\end{center}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% lowercase roman numerals for pre-document stuff
\begin{center}
\vspace*{2in}
ID\\
\vspace{1in}
By\\~\\
J\\
\vspace*{1in}
A Thesis Submitted to the Faculty of the University of  in Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the Degree of Master of Science: Computer Science\\~\\~\\~\\
U\\
CUU\\~\\
December 2017\ 
\end{center}
\chapter*{}
\begin{center}
\vfill
Copyright \copyright\ 2017

\bigskip

By J

\bigskip

All Rights Reserved
\vfill
\end{center}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ABSTRACT}
\large
\paragraph{ }

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
%\subfile{sections/Acknowledge}

\chapter*{DEDICATION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}DEDICATION}
%\subfile{sections/Dedication}


\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} 
\tableofcontents

\vspace{-4\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}

\chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
%\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
%\subfile{sections/Los}

\chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
%\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
%\subfile{sections/Loa}


\cleardoublepage
\cleardoublepage
\large
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro}
\section{Background}
\label{Backgrnd}
%\subfile{Sections/Background}

\section{Questions and Limitations}
\label{Quest}
%\subfile{Sections/quest}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
%\subfile{Sections/Relworks}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY}
\label{Method}
%\subfile{Sections/Methodology}

\chapter{RESULTS}
\label{Result}
%\subfile{Sections/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
%\subfile{Sections/conclusion}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1} 

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\string\@dotsep{10000}}
\makeatother
\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{APPENDIX }{}}

\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX  \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\string\@dotsep{100}}  
\makeatother
\chapter{Equations }
\label{eqn}

\clearpage
\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
\end{document}
```

I can't figure out where I need to change the code to make it to be 0.8 inches and size 12 pt font.
Thank You

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading `cleveref` too early. What do you mean by the 'footer margin' exactly? You don't currently have footers, do you? So it doesn't matter what font size they are.

Comment: The footer is the page number, and it needs to be size 12.